# How to (quickly) determine whether a function is totally differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying up for an exam, and an example question is:

> Show that the function $f(x,y):=(x^2y-\frac13y^3, \; \frac13 x^3-xy^2)$ is fully differentiable and determine its derivative.

Now I'm able to solve this with about a page of tedious writing, but since it's an exam question I figured there must be a quick(er) way to do this. Hence this question.

My solution would be to calculate partial derivatives and plugging them (pairwise) in to the limit of the derivative so that we may show both the first and second element of the $f(\textbf{v})$ vector to go to zero. (Using the definition saying that if
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-A(h)|}{|h|}=0,$$
then $f'(x) = A$ with $A$ a linear transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The partial derivatives of component functions $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ exist and are continuous, this is a quick way to check whether $f$ is differentiable, then the linear map is just the Jacobian.